# Warn command discord.py postgres sql error

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

So i made a warn command from a youtube tutorial for my discord bot from https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBwVvFWzp01YMD9ibqhSkEg

and i got this error

> data = await self.bot.db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM warnlogs WHERE
> guild_id = $1 AND member_id = $2", guild_id, member_id)
> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchrow'

code:

```
import datetime
import discord
import asyncpg
from discord.ext import commands


class Warn(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.loop.run_until_complete(self.create_db_pool())

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warnlogs (guild_id BIGINT, member_id BIGINT, warns TEXT[], times DECIMAL[])")
        print("warn system ready")

    async def create_db_pool(self):
        self.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="warn", user="postgres", password="")
        #self.bot.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database_url, ssl="require") when hosting the bot

    async def warn_log(self, guild_id, member_id):
        data = await self.bot.db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM warnlogs WHERE guild_id = $1 AND member_id = $2", guild_id, member_id)
        if not data:
            return []
        return data

    async def warn_entry(self, guild_id, member_id, reason, times):
        data = await self.warn_log(guild_id, member_id)
        if data == []:
            await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT INTO warnlogs (guild_id, member_id, warns, times) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)", guild_id, member_id, [reason], [times])
            return
        warns = data[2]
        times = data[3]
        warns.append(reason)
        times.append(times)
        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE warnlogs SET times = $1, warns = $2 WHERE guild_id = $3 AND member_id = $4", times, warns, guild_id, member_id)

    @commands.command()
    async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        if member == ctx.author or member == self.bot.user:
            return await ctx.send("You cant mute yourself or the bot.")
        await self.warn_entry(ctx.guild.id, member.id, reason, ctx.message.created_at.timestamp())
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has warned {member.name} \nReason: {reason}")
        data = await self.warn_log(ctx.guild.id, member.id)
        count = len(data[3])
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Warned by {ctx.author.name}", colour=discord.Colour.red(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=reason)
        embed.add_field(name="Total warns", value=f"**{count}** warns\n More than 5 warns a week can have serious consequences.")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        try:
            await member.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            pass


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Warn(bot))
```

so is there any way to fix this error if so can you please send the rewritten code it would be very helpful. And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you create connection pool into 'self.db'.

```
self.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="warn", user="postgres", password="")
```

But then you are calling fetchrow function on 'self.bot.db', which doesn't contain your connection pool. You have to call 'self.db.fetchrow' instead of 'self.bot.db.fetchrow'.

Change this:

```
data = await self.bot.db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM warnlogs WHERE guild_id = $1 AND member_id = $2", guild_id, member_id)
```

For this:

```
data = await self.db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM warnlogs WHERE guild_id = $1 AND member_id = $2", guild_id, member_id)
```

And you should change 'self.bot.db.execute' to 'self.db.execute'.

Once you are hosting bot you will have to uncomment this part:

```
#self.bot.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database_url, ssl="require") when hosting the bot
```

And use 'self.bot.db' instead of 'self.db'.

Comment: So i followed what you said and changed 'self.db.fetchrow' to 'self.bot.db.fetchrow' and got the error 
`return Result(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given`

Comment: also after i tried changing 'self.bot.db.execute' to 'self.db.execute' and ran the code along i got this error

Comment: result = await executor(stmt, None)
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 183, in bind_execute
  File "asyncpg\protocol\prepared_stmt.pyx", line 197, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $1: [Decimal('1642986769.6710000038146972656... (non-homogeneous array)

Comment: i am getting a asyncpg error with value non homogenous array.